# Authenticating WCF Service - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, wcf, authentication

I am following http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647294.aspx to add authentication to a WCF. My SQL Server is on a different machine than the development server. In Step 1, I am not using SQLExpress but using SQL Server 2012.  When I get to the Step 8: Create a User in the User Store, under Security Tab of ASP.net Web Site Administration Tool I see the following message:

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or     credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:  Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used with Windows authentication.
```

So looks like setting Windows Authentication is the problem. I am not sure what in the multi-step process I have to modify to add authentication to my WCF. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The example in Your link Access to SQL server is given to a local user NetworkService. This is the default Identity for the Application pool.

In Your case you cannot use a local user account, since the SQL Server is on a different machine.

You need to:

- Create a domain account
- Grant Access to SQL server to that domain account
- Change the Identity for Your Application pool to that of the domain accout

Comment: I don't think I can quite understand how to do the three things you  mentioned. Where and how do I create the domain account, in SQL Server Management Studio? What options do I need to choose to make the account a domain account? Then I think in IIS I would have to change the identity of the Application Pool, I see two options, either Built-in account or Custom account, which one do I choose and for either choice what would be the relationship between this choice and the domain account I created in the previous step?